# Ubuntu 14.10 PPC live DVD/USB?

Tags: live-usb, 14.10, livedvd, powerpc, alternate

I'm probably stretching things with this but would anyone know where or how to obtain a live disk image of Ubuntu 14.10 for PowerPC? I can't use the server install because the Ethernet port is busted on my eMac so I really don't have a strong and reliable connection to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Links to Ubuntu PowerPC images can be [found on the official wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCDownloads).